# Java xslt not working when jared

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xslt, jar

My problem only occurs when I jar my application. It works fine from under eclipse.

This is what loggs:

javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot find external method 'com.intellgis.saxonTransformExtensions.TransformCoordinates.convertGMLPosList' (must be public)

(I also get similar errors for methods that are in other libraries I wrote earlier)

From what I can think of it probably occurs because the system java doesn't have the correct classpath specified.

The question is:

How can I fix it (add a classpath to the xsl file).

**Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-api-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-epsg-wkt-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-main-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-metadata-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-opengis-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/gt-referencing-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jai_core-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jts-1.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/resolver.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/saxonTransformExtension.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/serializer.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/vecmath-1.3.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xalan.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xercesImpl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xercesSamples.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xml-apis.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Do you have that class somewhere in your jar? What is the classpath now?

Comment: I have it both in my jar and extracted outside and it doesn't work. The classpath is relative lib/saxonTransformExtensions, etc.

Comment: I think that my xsl starts a java process with no classpath added to it.

Comment: You need to show where all these files are, how you set the classpath, and how you run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse project has defined some dependencies which are not part of the standard jvm, otherwise your eclipse project cannot find the com.intellgis classes.

You need to add these jars to your classpath by either setting the CLASS_PATH environment variable or passing it on to the java or javaw executable. More information on this can be found on the tools documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

See also this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: That's what I'm asking for but I need to add classpath information inside the xsl as it starts a different java process.

Comment: Neither setting -classpath and adding CLASSPATH doesn't fix the errors